# Scroll bar works partially when hovering over list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, material-ui, scroll

I have made a contacts table using typescript and MUI.
When i hover over the table and scroll down, the table's scroll bar works inconsistently...
Sometimes it lets me scroll on the first try, sometimes i need to press the table to be able to scroll, and sometimes it doesn't work at all and i need to manually drag the scroll bar down.

This is the MUI table container inside the return section of the full contacts table component:

```
          <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <TableContainer
              onScroll={handleScroll}
              // dynamic scroll bar styling variations by selectedOption's value
              sx={{
                "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
                  width: "5px",
                },

                "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
                  background: selectedOption === "apps" ? "#6F5328" : "#3C583D",
                  borderRadius: "10px",
                },
                "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover": {
                  background: selectedOption === "apps" ? "#c4821d" : "#4d9450",
                },
                height: "29em",
                overflowX: "hidden",
              }}
            >
              <Table stickyHeader aria-label="a dense table">
                <TableBody>
                  <ClientOnly
                    fallback={
                      <TableRow
                        sx={{
                          "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 },
                        }}
                      ></TableRow>
                    }
                  >
                    {/* shownContacts is the searched value when there is one and it's the partial array of contacts when there is no search */}
                    {() =>
                      shownContacts.map((contact) => {
                        return (
                          <TableRow
                            key={contact.id}
                            sx={{
                              "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
                                border: 0,
                              },
                              "&:hover": {
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06)",
                              },
                              height: "5rem",
                            }}
                            onClick={() => {
                              handleSelectedRow(contact);
                            }}
                          >
                            <TableCell>
                              <Typography
                                variant="body2"
                                sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                              >
                                {contact.firstName + " " + contact.lastName}
                              </Typography>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                              <Typography
                                variant="body2"
                                sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                              >
                                {hebrewUnitRelations[contact.unit]}
                              </Typography>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                              <Typography
                                variant="body2"
                                sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                              >
                                {
                                  BaseJobRelations[contact.unit].filter(
                                    (value) => value.value === contact.branch
                                  )[0]?.name
                                }
                              </Typography>
                            </TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        );
                      })
                    }
                  </ClientOnly>
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Suspense>
```

FYI: I have another scrollable Box component (a basic MUI div) that works just fine.

Thanks for your time :)

I have tried rearranging the zIndex of the components inside, and yet to switch out of the MUI TableContainer component format.